# Require module with property dynamic Node - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

How can I access a property of a require dynamically,

Instead of doing

```
 let module = require ("path"). get;
 let module = require ("path"). create;
```

I would like to do;

```
var property = "get";
let module = require ("path"). property;

var property = "create";
let module = require ("path"). property;
```

To be able to have a single line and the property dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of that `let module = require ("path"). property;`

make that `let module = require ("path")[property];`

that should work.

If you want a more fancy way

`let module = require ("path")[<some_condition> ? 'get' : 'create'];`